# Get month wise count from Mysql database even if there are no results

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am creating graph for display month wise count from Mysql database.

**Execute this following query:**

```
$cash_query =  $this->db->query("select COUNT(*) as count_monthwise, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_added)) as month from `order` where user_id='1'  and status != '9' and payment_type = '1' GROUP BY month");
$cash_result = $cash_query->result();
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count_monthwise] => 1
            [month] => 8
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count_monthwise] => 2
            [month] => 9
        )

)
```

In above output, there are display "count_monthwise" means count and month "8" means "8th month - August".

But i want to display output with all months, if find count are `0` in any months, then display `[count_monthwise] => 0`.

**I want to display Exact output like:**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count_monthwise] => 1
                [month] => 1
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count_monthwise] => 1
                [month] => 2
            )
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            . 
        [10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count_monthwise] => 0
                [month] => 11
            )
        [11] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count_monthwise] => 0
                [month] => 12
            )

    )
```

I have used using foreach loop something like this, but this is not working.

**Loop**

```
foreach($cash_result as $cash => $cash_value){
   for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++){
      if($i == $cash){
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: if($array[2]->month='2') {  $array[2]->count_monthwise=0;   $array[2]->moth=2; }  do something in php

Comment: don't complex query just loop the result and add ur needs, just have a look on answer given by me

Comment: @neel does it worked, let me know if anything else u need?

Comment: @Kool-Mind It is working. But there are problem that, in all months display count '0'

Comment: so what u want instead of it

Comment: there are not getting count..i think there something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

That could be the one way around:

```
SELECT 
 COALESCE(yourQuery.count_monthwise,0) AS monthwise_count,
 allMonths.month
(SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 ) AS allMonths
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as count_monthwise, 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(dt_added)) as month 
 from `order` 
 where user_id='1'  and status != '9' and payment_type = '1' 
 GROUP BY month
) AS yourQuery 
ON allMonths.month = yourQuery.month
```

Answer (score 0):

use below way after getting the result from database don't do complex query just do some code twist

```
$cash_result = $cash_query->result_array(); // make it to array         
$month = range(1,12);  // month array
$new_array = array();
$counta = count($month);
for($i=0; $i<$counta ; $i++){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$row){
       if(($month[$i] == $row['month'])){
          $new_array[$i] = $arr[$key]; 
          break;
       }else{
          $new_array[$i] = array('count_monthwise' => 0,'month' => $month[$i]);       
       }
    }
}   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($new_array);
```